# gym.spaces.box Observation State Understanding

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

So i'm trying to perform some reinforcement learning in a custom environment using gym however I'm very confused as to how spaces.box works. What do each of the parameters mean? If I have a a game state that involves lots of information such as the hp of characters, their stats and abilities as an example, I'm not really sure something like this would be represented in Box as an observation state. Also in a game with a lot of abilities, would it be better to one-hot encode them or leave them as regular incremental Id's since i want to use a neural network to find expected Q values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`spaces.Box` means that you are dealing with real-valued quantities.

For example:

`action_space = spaces.Box(np.array([-1,0,1]), np.array([1,1,2]))`

Here the actions are 3-dimensional. Also, `[-1,0,1]` is the lowest accepted value and `[1,1,2]` is the highest accepted value.

In essence, `a=[a1,a2,a3]`,

`a1` is in the range [-1,1], `a2` is in the range [0,1], `a3` is in the range [1,2].

If there are a lot of "abilities" with a huge variety then the state vector might become quite huge if one uses one-hot encoding. Hence it would be advisable to use regular incremental IDs. But normalise them to the range [0,1] so that the neural network activations don't saturate.

Comment: Can you elaborate on normalizing so activation networks dont saturate?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow up on this question. When I try to implement this code I get the error:

```
    AttributeError: 'Box' object has no attribute 'spaces'
```

Does this method still work?

Comment: Is your code like "<Box object>.spaces"? Here space is the upper package of Box, "from gym.spaces.box import Box".  You can "print(<Box object>.__dir__())" to list all the attributes. The output would be "['dtype', 'shape', 'low', 'high', 'bounded_below', 'bounded_above', 'np_random', '__module__'...]". Box.dtype, .shape, .low, .high are very useful.